# Measure program runtime statistically sound

Tags: linux, command-line, statistics, runtime, benchmarking

Assume I have two variants of my compiled program, `./foo` and `./bar`, and I want to find out if `bar` is indeed faster.

I can compare runtimes by running `time ./foo` and `time ./bar`, but the numbers vary too much to get a meaningful result here.

What is the quickest way to get a statistically sound comparisons of two command line program execution times? E.g. one that also tells me about the variance of the measurements?

Comment: If number varies a lot, it would be interesting to understand why ? Is it working on same data sample, is it too small ? is the first run more exensive ?

Comment: All of that, likely, and other reasons (browser running at the same time etc.). Nevertheless, for a one-shot measurement, just repeating the test is more efficient than understanding and rooting out these problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python module `timeit` also provides a simple command line interface, which is already much more convenient than issuing `time` commands multiple times:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'import os' 'os.system("./IsSpace-before")'
10 loops, best of 3: 4.9 sec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'import os' 'os.system("./IsSpace-after")'
10 loops, best of 3: 4.9 sec per loop
```

The timeit module does not calculate averages and variances, but simply takes the minimum, on the basis that all measurement errors *increase* the measurement.